# Bluetooth Low Energy Change access the remote device

Tags: android, bluetooth, remote-access, bluetooth-lowenergy

I start a project in which we are implementing the **BLE** to access the **BLE** enable the device in android. But My Question is what we change the **BLE** enable Device Setting through our android phone **It is Possible OR Not?

If this is performed by another way in android to change the remote device setting please provide Any help, suggestion, tutorials would be highly appreciated. Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can change BLE device characteristics by BluetoothGattCharacteristic's writeCharacteristic method. If particular BLE device service has write property.

**Reference Links**

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html
3. http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/
4. https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Toolbox

Comment: Thanks.. @Piyush  But my concern is  when I connect the app to device after that how can we change particular characteristics Like. Device on/off, brightness and other seating.

Comment: Devices provide services like Battery Service which has characteristics for example Battery Level, if Battery Level has write property then you can change it. for BLE Service and Characteristics Link: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx